# Unhandled rejection Error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first

Tags: ethereum, web3js

Im currently trying to use Infura to run on my machine thru Web3. When I set to run my `node index.js` file I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first.
    at Object._processExecuteArguments (/Users/Oso.Lu/cryptokitty-miner/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:739:15)
    at Object._executeMethod (/Users/Oso.Lu/cryptokitty-miner/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:760:54


var helpers = require("./helpers.js")

var Web3 = require('web3');
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

// You should be running a local Eth node or use Infura.
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io:443"));
var prompt = require('prompt');


var sendingAddress = "********************"  // with your sending ETH address
var pKey = "******************************"; // This will store the corresponding private key.  we'll be getting the private key for this Eth address from a command prompt


// Keep track of kitties we'll mine to avoid double-mining
var kittyArray = []

var theNonce = "";
// Gas price.   Todo: Use Eth gas station Oracle to predict gas prices
var gwei = '26'

// Track # of received
var num_requested = 0
var num_received = 0
```

I thought maybe the issue is running on Infura port 443.

Comment: This usually means you haven't set MyContract.options.address to the address returned from the contract instance after deployment. You'll need to post your complete code to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Simple solution

```
Voting.options.address = "0x6ee9957aef5f4073c6af71441ec7962527c37671"
```

where **Voting** is my **smart contract instance** name

"**0x6ee9957aef5f4073c6af71441ec7962527c37671**" is ***deployed smart contact address***

my web3.js version 
 **"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.31",**

Comment: where we have to write 'Voting.options.address = "0x6ee9957aef5f4073c6af71441ec7962527c37671"' ?

Comment: I have the same error that you got. Have you figure out where to add this code that @ngCourse recommend to add?

Comment: Please mention the file where we need to add the above code.

Answer (score 2):

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
this.setState({ 'account': accounts[0] });
const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
const networkData = SocialNetwork.networks[networkId]
if (networkData) {
    const socialNetwork = web3.eth.Contract(SocialNetwork.abi, networkData.address)

} else {
    window.alert('oops')
}
```

This is the right way to set an address for your Contract. You can set the address by **networkData.address**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks alot for this conversation, just started off with truffle in local environment and ran into this issue;
It got solved ,
after this code in App.js
`

```
const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );
```

`
just addded this :

`instance.options.address = " contract address on particular testnent ";`

can be found in CONTRACT_NAME.js in networks where the network_id is 5777"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I realized that my directory was missing in my truffle-config.js file, which is why my networks field in migration.sol wasn't getting updated. I had to add the following line to fulfill the

contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),